# MySQL "LIKE" ignores result with Russian words

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with titles in Cyrillic alphabet. `LIKE` seems to ignore certain words in Russian. Collation `UTF8_general_ci`. I tried execute request from php as well as from PHPMyAdmin. What can be possible reason?

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE 'слово'
```

UPD: Here is example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30d904/1/0

Comment: First of all, could you prepare minimal reproducible example with concrete data.
Did you try to use wildcard characters? For example `LIKE '%слово%'`

Comment: Hi, How can I create reproducible database? My hosting does not allow outside connections to Database. 
I tried wildcards and it works, but it defeats my purpose because I need to find exact word match in strings.

Comment: There are free public tools for it: http://sqlfiddle.com/ , https://www.db-fiddle.com/ , or you can put SQL DDL and a couple of inserts here. Only meaningful fields.

Comment: If you tried wildcards and it works then it should work without them too. But why `column LIKE 'слово'` and not `column = 'слово'`?

Comment: @artoodetoo - thanks for tip, added sqlfiddle.

Comment: @forpas - I need to get rows where string contains word. I added an example

Comment: @RovshanMamedov check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM videos 
WHERE LOWER(`title`) REGEXP '[[:<:]]все[[:>:]]'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62292ea/1

The regular expression pattern works with word boundaries (space, comma, etc.) as well as with begin|end of string. I applied lower() function for case insensitivity.
So it matches *"Все в гости к нам"* and doesn't match *"Повсеместно"*

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I haven't seen REGEX pattern like this before. I guess this is better answer to my problem

Answer (score 1):

try like this :

```
SELECT * FROM videos WHERE title LIKE '% все %'
```

just add `%` at the beginning and the end of your search string (word).

for example. change `'все'` to `'% все %'`.

[Your Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30d904/9)

But if you want it to be not case sensitive then

```
SELECT * FROM videos WHERE LOWER(title) LIKE LOWER('% все %')
```

[Not case sensitive Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30d904/6)

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work for me, because if I include wildcards it will include results with other words which can contain this word. For example "%все%" (translates like "all") will return results with words "всегда" (translates "always") I temporarily used a workaround to this using LIKE '% все %'. (Added spaces to make sure that it searches a word) but this is workaround and I have to know what is real reason behind my problem.

Comment: Spaces is not a silver bullet. I suppose you'd like to get word at the very begining or end of the string too, also it can be surrounded by "," and other separators. I guess the only solution is regular expression. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
WHERE title LIKE 'все'
```

the query matches titles that are equal to `'все'` because `LIKE` without wildcards is equivalent to `=` (with the possible exception of case sensitivity).
But you want titles that **contain** the word `'все'`, meaning titles that would be anywhere inside the column value preceded and followed by a space (except when it is at the start or at the end). 
So use the operator `LIKE` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM videos 
WHERE CONCAT(' ', title, ' ') LIKE '% все %'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4iNBvVk5UfhAgqdirf1Yhm/00).
Results:

```
| ID  | title                      | description | upload_time         | file_name                          | hosted | video_uri | play_count |
| --- | -------------------------- | ----------- | ------------------- | ---------------------------------- | ------ | --------- | ---------- |
| 539 | И все будет хорошо дай бог |             | 2019-12-17 05:01:25 | uploads/4766__все_будет_хорошо.mp4 | 1      | 379928030 | 1          |
| 566 | Да и вообще вы все молодцы |             | 2019-12-17 22:47:47 | uploads/7118__все_молодцы.mp4      | 0      |           | 0          |
| 614 | Ну это сразу все объясняет |             | 2019-12-20 09:19:04 | uploads/3522__это_сразу_все_.mp4   | 1      | 380654168 | 2          |
```

Comment: Yes, I came up with something similar in the end, but I bluntly added spaces in PHP when formed sql :) Your solution is much more elegant.  If you don't mind I won't mark your answer for a while, I want to see if someone knows what is a real reason behind this problem. I suspect something with collation and encoding.

Comment: @RovshanMamedov I added an explanation in my answer.

Comment: OK, that explains it. I always thought of LIKE as a loose search inside a string. Thank you for explaining this to me. (I probably will get more downvotes for this comment, but I can't leave without thanks :)

Comment: No, I don't believe this would cause any downvotes. Don't hesitate to ask. Just make sure that you provide all the explanations, sample data and expected results needed so the question is clear. This is the fastest way to get answers.

Comment: @forpas how about separators different from space?

Comment: @artoodetoo there aren't any in the OP's data. The column contains movie titles (I think).